# Is there any problem with my usage of printf function?

Tags: c

I have been given the following task to perform in C: -

*The year is divided into four seasons: spring, summer, fall and winter. While the exact dates that the seasons change vary a little bit from year to year because of the way that the calendar is constructed, we will use the following dates for this exercise:*

*Season First day

Summer March 20

Spring June 21

Fall September 22

Winter December 21*

*Create a program that reads a month and day from the user. The user will enter the name of the month as a string, followed by the day within the month as an integer.*

*Then your program should display the season associated with the date that was entered.*

*Note: Enter First three letter for month example: Jan for january, Feb for Feburary ans so on....and first letter of the month should be capital.*

I wrote a mini test code to check the first condition, that is *Mar 20.*

Here is my code: -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
int date;
char month[3];

printf("Enter the month\n");
scanf("%s",month);

printf("Enter the date\n");
scanf("%d",&date);

int temp;
temp= strcmp(month,"Mar");
printf("output is %d\n",temp);
return 0;
}
```

The problem which I am getting is that while giving input as *Mar* and *20*, I am getting output: - *"output is 20"*. Whereas i am suppose to get output as 0 in my test code.

One more observation is that if I change the date to any random number, I am getting that as the output, whereas i am suppose to get the value which is stored in Temp, i.e. 0.

I am getting correct output if i remove variable *date* completely from the code. At that time I am getting 0.

Comment: Const char *argv[]?? That's not a valid parameter!

Comment: `char month[3]` can only store 2 characters, since the third will be `\0`

Comment: `month` has space for 3 characters. "Jan" needs space for 4 characters! You cannot put 4 horses in 3 stables!

Comment: Currently coding on Xcode. By default it has these parameters: -*argv[]

Comment: @machine_1: adding `const` to the 2nd argument doesn't make it invalid.

Comment: The problem with the `argv` declaration is the `const`.  Its appearance there is inconsistent with the language specifications, though that's unlikely to present an issue in practice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. After putting the array size as 4, i am getting the correct answer. But i have a question though, Why was my code then copying the input of date in my output?

Comment: Using `const` that way does not make the argument invalid, @pmg, but it does rely on the implementation to accept that form of `main` declaration *as an extension* (which the standard explicitly permits it to do).  The standard requires support for a signature *without* `const`, and that signature is not compatible with the OP's.

Comment: @SwarnimKhosla It could be a coincidence that strcmp returned 20, when a string is not null terminated, reading it may continue until another null is found in memory. Date may also be overwriting the null that was written outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @Patrick You are absolutely right. Howsoever when I type any other number which does not have 0 in it's unit digit, then i am getting output as 6. I wonder why?

Comment: @SwarnimKhosla You can try printf("%s", month); to see exactly what the program is interpreting as a string and compare that to what you're inputting.

Comment: @Patrick I am really getting very wierd output. When I input Mar 20, in output I am getting Mar; but when I input Mar 21, Then I am getting output as 21\n Mar. Really wierd.

Comment: @machine_1, what???  `const char *argv[]` is not a valid parameter?  where do you get that?

Comment: @LuisColorado See 5.1.2.2.1 of the standard. Its says: "_It shall be defined with a return type of `int`  and with no parameters: `int main(void) { /* ... */ }` or with two parameters: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }` or equivalent or in some other implementation defined manner._"  So, if the implementation defines main as `int main(int argc, const char *argv[])`, then it's fine, otherwise, it is not compatible with the standard definition.

Comment: @machine_1, of course not, but the `const` keyword in C is used to let the compiler to disallow you modifying the array pointed values.  As a security net for programmers, there's no difference in implementation details and mostly all compilers allow that extension (it's not in the standard, but a standard _de facto_)  Apply some common sense when discussing here, please.  Sorry, but to read the standard, i don't need SO, but only the standard.  Should that disallow also the `int argc, char **argv` way also?  The standard says that but It doesn't enumerate that third way of saying it.

Comment: @Luis It does in the footnote...

Comment: @machine_1, footnotes are normally not part of the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of your printf function is correct, your printing an integer using the correct conversion specifier for it '%d', as documented on https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

What may **not be fine** is the variable 'month'.
It is a char buffer with 3 bytes for storage. You are using it to stored null terminated strings, so it can only store 2 ASCII characters + the null terminator.

Another concern is how the scanf function is used for getting the month string.
If you do not specify a field width, things can get ugly, see https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that C strings include a 0-valued terminator, so to store an N-character string, you need a character array that's at least N+1 elements wide.

String management functions like `strcmp` rely on that terminator to tell them where the end of the string is.  The likely reason you're getting weird output is that the string constant `"Mar"` is 0-terminated, while the string stored in your `month` array is not, so `strcmp` is reading past the end of the `month` array until it sees a 0-valued byte and is returning the difference between `"Mar"` and `"Marx"`, where *`x`* represents some unknown sequence of bytes.

Accessing memory past the end of an array results in *undefined behavior*, and any result is possible.

To fix this particular issue, declare `month` as a 4-element array of `char` and limit the input to 3 characters on the `scanf` call:

```
char month[4];
...
scanf( "%3s", month );
```

The standard signature of `main` is either

```
int main( void )
```

or

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ); // NOT const
```

The `argv` array is supposed to be modifiable:

> **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**
> ...
> — The parameters **`argc`** and **`argv`** and the strings pointed to by the **`argv`** array shall
> be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
> startup and program termination.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>